# Printing labels in html/css broke suddenly

Tags: html, css, printing

I have a printing page in a website that prints labels for shoes as the picture shows. This had been working for more than 3 years. Two days ago, this broke as shown, the labels or page-break-after stopped working properly.

I looked online but could not know what went wrong.

The correct behaviour is to view each label in a page, so the label printer can print it correctly.

Code:
CSS

```css
  h1, h3, h2, h4 {
    margin-bottom: 1px;
  }
  h6 {
    margin: 0px;
    direction: ltr;
  }

  .col-4, .col-2, .col-8 {
    padding: 1px;
  }

  @page {
    size: 10cm 5cm;
    margin: 0.2cm;
  }

    img {
      width: 95%;
      height: 60px;
    }   

  p.att-value {
    font-family: 'Almarai', sans-serif;
    font-size: larger;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px;
  }
  span.value-block {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
  }

  .a-label {
    height: 10cm;
    width: 5cm;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 0.1cm;
  }


  @media print{
    html, body {
      width: 10cm;
      height: 5cm;
    }   
    .pagebreak {
      break-inside: avoid;
      break-after: page;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="a-label">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxCHC.png">
      <h6>123456</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h3>Shoe Name</h3>
      <p class="att-value">
        <span class="value-block">Product Name</span>
        <span class="value-block">Size: 36</span>
        <span class="att-value"> 250 usd</span>
     </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pagebreak"></div>



<div class="a-label">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxCHC.png">
      <h6>123456</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h3>Shoe Name 2</h3>
      <p class="att-value">
        <span class="value-block">Product Name</span>
        <span class="value-block">Size: 36</span>
        <span class="att-value"> 250 usd</span>
     </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pagebreak"></div>
```

This feature broke on all browsers

[image: It used to be each label in a separated page]

Comment: Without code we can't know what's happen, have you try to debug?

Comment: @Sfili_81 I updated the code now

Comment: Does any part of the page (e.g. fonts or JavaScript) come from a CDN that could have "updated" it?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes I am using bootstrap rtl

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rtlcss.com/bootstrap/v4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-vus3nQHTD+5mpDiZ4rkEPlnkcyTP+49BhJ4wJeJunw06ZAp+wzzeBPUXr42fi8If" crossorigin="anonymous">

However I have not changed it!

Comment: I updated bootstrap to a newer version, no changes!
The issue happened suddenly.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after I updated to the latest bootstrap, specifically version 5.
It is unclear to me why it broke suddenly. This feature worked 3 years.

So, the comment from @AndrewMorton was helpful. The credit goes to him.